# Magento CE Patch 7405 failing

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, patches, supee-7405

I have just tried installing patch 7405 on a magento CE version 1.9.0.1. However it has come up with the following error message.

---

SUPEE-7405 Error output:

```
[aspenofh@sipuk3-17 html]$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-45-14.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
[...]
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 227.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Io/File.php.rej
```

---

The contents of lib/Varien/Io/File.php.rej

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Varien
 * @package     Varien_Io
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


/**
 * Filesystem client
 *
 * @category   Varien
 * @package    Varien_Io
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */    class Varien_Io_File extends Varien_Io_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Save initial working directory
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_iwd;

    /**
     * Use virtual current working directory for application integrity
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_cwd;

    /**
     * Used to grep ls() output
     *
     * @const
     */
    const GREP_FILES = 'files_only';

    /**
     * Used to grep ls() output
     *
     * @const
     */
    const GREP_DIRS = 'dirs_only';

    /**
     * If this variable is set to TRUE, our library will be able to automaticaly create
     * non-existant directories.
     *
     * @var bool
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_allowCreateFolders = false;

    /**
     * Stream open file pointer
     *
     * @var resource
     */
    protected $_streamHandler;

    /**
     * Stream mode filename
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_streamFileName;

    /**
     * Stream mode chmod
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_streamChmod;

    /**
     * Lock file
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_streamLocked = false;

    /**
     * Destruct
     */
    public function __destruct()
    {
        if ($this->_streamHandler) {
            $this->streamClose();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open file in stream mode
     * For set folder for file use open method
     *
     * @param string $fileName
     * @param string $mode
     * @return bool
     */
    public function streamOpen($fileName, $mode = 'w+', $chmod = 0666)
    {
        $writeableMode = preg_match('#^[wax]#i', $mode);
        if ($writeableMode && !is_writeable($this->_cwd)) {
            throw new Exception('Permission denied for write to ' . $this->_cwd);
        }

        if (!ini_get('auto_detect_line_endings')) {
            ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', 1);
        }

        @chdir($this->_cwd);
        $this->_streamHandler = @fopen($fileName, $mode);
        @chdir($this->_iwd);
        if ($this->_streamHandler === false) {
            throw new Exception('Error write to file ' . $fileName);
        }

        $this->_streamFileName = $fileName;
        $this->_streamChmod = $chmod;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Lock file
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function streamLock($exclusive = true)
    {
        if (!$this->_streamHandler) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->_streamLocked = true;
        $lock = $exclusive ? LOCK_EX : LOCK_SH;
        return flock($this->_streamHandler, $lock);
    }

    /**
     * Unlock file
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function streamUnlock()
    {
        if (!$this->_streamHandler || !$this->_streamLocked) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->_streamLocked = false;
        return flock($this->_streamHandler, LOCK_UN);
    }

    /**
     * Binary-safe file read
     *
     * @param int $length
     * @return string
     */
    public function streamRead($length = 1024)
    {
        if (!$this->_streamHandler) {
            return false;
        }
        if (feof($this->_streamHandler)) {
            return false;
        }
        return @fgets($this->_streamHandler, $length);
    }

    /**
     * Gets line from file pointer and parse for CSV fields
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function streamReadCsv($delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"')
    {
        if (!$this->_streamHandler) {
            return false;
        }
        return @fgetcsv($this->_streamHandler, 0, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    }

    /**
     * Binary-safe file write
     *
     * @param string $str
     * @return bool
     */
    public function streamWrite($str)
    {
        if (!$this->_streamHandler) {
            return false;
        }
        return @fwrite($this->_streamHandler, $str);
    }

    /**
     * Format line as CSV and write to file pointer
     *
     * @param array $row
     * @param string $delimiter
     * @param string $enclosure
     * @return bool|int
     */
    public function streamWriteCsv(array $row, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"')
    {
        if (!$this->_streamHandler) {
            return false;
        }
        return @fputcsv($this->_streamHandler, $row, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    }

    /**
     * Close an open file pointer
     * Set chmod on a file
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function streamClose()
    {
        if (!$this->_streamHandler) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->_streamLocked) {
            $this->streamUnlock();
        }
        @fclose($this->_streamHandler);
        $this->chmod($this->_streamFileName, $this->_streamChmod);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve open file statistic
     *
     * @param string $part the part of statistic
     * @param mixed $default default value for part
     * @return array|bool
     */
    public function streamStat($part = null, $default = null)
    {
        if (!$this->_streamHandler) {
            return false;
        }
        $stat = @fstat($this->_streamHandler);
        if (!is_null($part)) {
            return isset($stat[$part]) ? $stat[$part] : $default;
        }
        return $stat;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve stream methods exception
     *
     * @return Exception
     */
    public function getStreamException()
    {
        return $this->_streamException;
    }

    /**
     * Open a connection
     *
     * Possible arguments:
     * - path     default current path
     *
     * @param array $args
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function open(array $args=array())
    {
        if (!empty($args['path']) && $this->_allowCreateFolders) {
            $this->checkAndCreateFolder($args['path']);
        }

        $this->_iwd = getcwd();
        $this->cd(!empty($args['path']) ? $args['path'] : $this->_iwd);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Used to set {@link _allowCreateFolders} value
     *
     * @param mixed $flag
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAllowCreateFolders($flag)
    {
        $this->_allowCreateFolders = $flag;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Close a connection
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function close()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Create a directory
     *
     * @param string $dir
     * @param int $mode
     * @param boolean $recursive
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function mkdir($dir, $mode=0777, $recursive=true)
    {
        if ($this->_cwd) {
            chdir($this->_cwd);
        }

        $result = @mkdir($dir, $mode, $recursive);
        if ($result) {
            @chmod($dir, $mode);
        }
        if ($this->_iwd) {
            chdir($this->_iwd);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Delete a directory
     *
     * @param string $dir
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function rmdir($dir, $recursive = false)
    {
        if ($this->_cwd) {
            @chdir($this->_cwd);
        }
        $result = self::rmdirRecursive($dir, $recursive);
        @chdir($this->_iwd);
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Delete a directory recursively
     * @param string $dir
     * @param bool $recursive
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function rmdirRecursive($dir, $recursive = true)
    {
        if ($recursive) {
            if (is_dir($dir)) {
                foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
                    if (!strcmp($item, '.') || !strcmp($item, '..')) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    self::rmdirRecursive($dir . "/" . $item, $recursive);
                }
                $result = @rmdir($dir);
            } else {
                $result = @unlink($dir);
            }
        } else {
            $result = @rmdir($dir);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Get current working directory
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function pwd()
    {
        return $this->_cwd;
    }

    /**
     * Change current working directory
     *
     * @param string $dir
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function cd($dir)
    {
        if( is_dir($dir) ) {
            @chdir($this->_iwd);
            $this->_cwd = realpath($dir);
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Unable to list current working directory.');
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read a file to result, file or stream
     *
     * If $dest is null the output will be returned.
     * Otherwise it will be saved to the file or stream and operation result is returned.
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @param string|resource $dest
     * @return boolean|string
     */
    public function read($filename, $dest=null)
    {
        if (!is_null($dest)) {
            chdir($this->_cwd);
            $result = @copy($filename, $dest);
            chdir($this->_iwd);
            return $result;
        }

        chdir($this->_cwd);
        $result = @file_get_contents($filename);
        chdir($this->_iwd);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Write a file from string, file or stream
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @param string|resource $src
     * @param int $mode
     *
     * @return int|boolean
     */
    public function write($filename, $src, $mode=null)
    {
        if (!$this->_IsValidSource($src) || !$this->_isFilenameWriteable($filename)) {
            return false;
        }

        $srcIsFile = $this->_checkSrcIsFile($src);
        if ($srcIsFile) {
            $src = realpath($src);
            $result = $this->cp($src, $filename);
        } else {
            $result = $this->filePutContent($filename, $src);
        }

        if (!is_null($mode) && $result !== false) {
            $this->chmod($filename, $mode);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Check source is valid
     *
     * @param string|resource $src
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _IsValidSource($src)
    {
        if (is_string($src) || is_resource($src)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check filename is writeable
     * If filename not exist check dirname writeable
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @throws Varien_Io_Exception
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isFilenameWriteable($filename)
    {
        $error = false;
        @chdir($this->_cwd);
         if (file_exists($filename)) {
            if (!is_writeable($filename)) {
                $error = "File '{$filename}' isn't writeable";
            }
        } else {
            $folder = dirname($filename);
            if (!is_writable($folder)) {
                $error = "Folder '{$folder}' isn't writeable";
            }
        }
        @chdir($this->_iwd);

        if ($error) {
            throw new Varien_Io_Exception($error);
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Check source is file
     *
     * @param string $src
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _checkSrcIsFile($src)
    {
        $result = false;
        if (is_string($src) && is_readable($src) && is_file($src)) {
            $result = true;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * File put content wrapper
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @param srting|resource $src
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function filePutContent($filename, $src)
    {
        @chdir($this->_cwd);
        $result = @file_put_contents($filename, $src);
        chdir($this->_iwd);

        return $result;
    }

    public function fileExists($file, $onlyFile = true)
    {
        @chdir($this->_cwd);
        $result = file_exists($file);
        if ($result && $onlyFile) {
            $result = is_file($file);
        }
        @chdir($this->_iwd);
        return $result;
    }

    public function isWriteable($path)
    {
        @chdir($this->_cwd);
        $result = is_writeable($path);
        @chdir($this->_iwd);
        return $result;
    }

    public function getDestinationFolder($filepath)
    {
        preg_match('/^(.*[!\/])/', $filepath, $mathces);
        if (isset($mathces[0])) {
            return $mathces[0];
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Create destination folder
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return Varien_Io_File
     */
    public function createDestinationDir($path)
    {
        if (!$this->_allowCreateFolders) {
            return false;
        }
        return $this->checkAndCreateFolder($this->getCleanPath($path));
    }

    /**
     * Check and create if not exists folder
     *
     * @param string $folder
     * @param int $mode
     * @throws Exception
     * @return bool
     */
    public function checkAndCreateFolder($folder, $mode = 0777)
    {
        if (is_dir($folder)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!is_dir(dirname($folder))) {
            $this->checkAndCreateFolder(dirname($folder), $mode);
        }
        if (!is_dir($folder) && !$this->mkdir($folder, $mode)) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to create directory '{$folder}'. Access forbidden.");
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Delete a file
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function rm($filename)
    {
        @chdir($this->_cwd);
        $result = @unlink($filename);
        @chdir($this->_iwd);
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Rename or move a directory or a file
     *
     * @param string $src
     * @param string $dest
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function mv($src, $dest)
    {
        chdir($this->_cwd);
        $result = @rename($src, $dest);
        chdir($this->_iwd);
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Copy a file
     *
     * @param string $src
     * @param string $dest
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function cp($src, $dest)
    {
        @chdir($this->_cwd);
        $result = @copy($src, $dest);
        @chdir($this->_iwd);
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Change mode of a directory or a file
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @param int $mode
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function chmod($filename, $mode)
    {
        if ($this->_cwd) {
            chdir($this->_cwd);
        }
        $result = @chmod($filename, $mode);
        if ($this->_iwd) {
            chdir($this->_iwd);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Get list of cwd subdirectories and files
     *
     * Suggestions (from moshe):
     * - Use filemtime instead of filectime for performance
     * - Change $grep to $flags and use binary flags
     *   - LS_DIRS  = 1
     *   - LS_FILES = 2
     *   - LS_ALL   = 3
     *
     * @param Varien_Io_File const
     * @access public
     * @return array
     */
    public function ls($grep=null)
    {
        $ignoredDirectories = Array('.', '..');

        if( is_dir($this->_cwd) ) {
            $dir = $this->_cwd;
        } elseif( is_dir($this->_iwd) ) {
            $dir = $this->_iwd;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Unable to list current working directory.');
        }

        $list = Array();

        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($entry = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                $list_item = Array();

                $fullpath = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $entry;

                if( ($grep == self::GREP_DIRS) && (!is_dir($fullpath)) ) {
                    continue;
                } elseif( ($grep == self::GREP_FILES) && (!is_file($fullpath)) ) {
                    continue;
                } elseif( in_array($entry, $ignoredDirectories) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                $list_item['text'] = $entry;
                $list_item['mod_date'] = date ('Y-m-d H:i:s', filectime($fullpath));
                $list_item['permissions'] = $this->_parsePermissions(fileperms($fullpath));
                $list_item['owner'] = $this->_getFileOwner($fullpath);

                if( is_file($fullpath) ) {
                    $pathinfo = pathinfo($fullpath);
                    $list_item['size'] = filesize($fullpath);
                    $list_item['leaf'] = true;
                    if( isset($pathinfo['extension'])
                        && in_array(strtolower($pathinfo['extension']), Array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp', 'png'))
                        && $list_item['size'] > 0
                    ) {
                        $list_item['is_image'] = true;
                        $list_item['filetype'] = $pathinfo['extension'];
                    } elseif( $list_item['size'] == 0 ) {
                        $list_item['is_image'] = false;
                        $list_item['filetype'] = 'unknown';
                    } elseif( isset($pathinfo['extension']) ) {
                        $list_item['is_image'] = false;
                        $list_item['filetype'] = $pathinfo['extension'];
                    } else {
                        $list_item['is_image'] = false;
                        $list_item['filetype'] = 'unknown';
                    }
                } else {
                    $list_item['leaf'] = false;
                    $list_item['id'] = $fullpath;
                }

                $list[] = $list_item;
            }
            closedir($dh);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Unable to list current working directory. Access forbidden.');
        }

        return $list;
    }

    /**
     * Convert integer permissions format into human readable
     *
     * @param integer $mode
     * @access protected
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _parsePermissions($mode)
    {
        if( $mode & 0x1000 )
            $type='p'; /* FIFO pipe */
        else if( $mode & 0x2000 )
            $type='c'; /* Character special */
        else if( $mode & 0x4000 )
            $type='d'; /* Directory */
        else if( $mode & 0x6000 )
            $type='b'; /* Block special */
        else if( $mode & 0x8000 )
            $type='-'; /* Regular */
        else if( $mode & 0xA000 )
            $type='l'; /* Symbolic Link */
        else if( $mode & 0xC000 )
            $type='s'; /* Socket */
        else
            $type='u'; /* UNKNOWN */

        /* Determine permissions */
        $owner['read'] = ($mode & 00400) ? 'r' : '-';
        $owner['write'] = ($mode & 00200) ? 'w' : '-';
        $owner['execute'] = ($mode & 00100) ? 'x' : '-';
        $group['read'] = ($mode & 00040) ? 'r' : '-';
        $group['write'] = ($mode & 00020) ? 'w' : '-';
        $group['execute'] = ($mode & 00010) ? 'x' : '-';
        $world['read'] = ($mode & 00004) ? 'r' : '-';
        $world['write'] = ($mode & 00002) ? 'w' : '-';
        $world['execute'] = ($mode & 00001) ? 'x' : '-';

        /* Adjust for SUID, SGID and sticky bit */
        if( $mode & 0x800 )
            $owner["execute"] = ($owner['execute']=='x') ? 's' : 'S';
        if( $mode & 0x400 )
            $group["execute"] = ($group['execute']=='x') ? 's' : 'S';
        if( $mode & 0x200 )
            $world["execute"] = ($world['execute']=='x') ? 't' : 'T';

        $s=sprintf('%1s', $type);
        $s.=sprintf('%1s%1s%1s', $owner['read'], $owner['write'], $owner['execute']);
        $s.=sprintf('%1s%1s%1s', $group['read'], $group['write'], $group['execute']);
        $s.=sprintf('%1s%1s%1s', $world['read'], $world['write'], $world['execute']);
        return trim($s);
    }

    /**
     * Get file owner
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @access protected
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getFileOwner($filename)
    {
        if( !function_exists('posix_getpwuid') ) {
            return 'n/a';
        }

        $owner     = posix_getpwuid(fileowner($filename));
        $groupinfo = posix_getgrnam(filegroup($filename));

        return $owner['name'] . ' / ' . $groupinfo;
    }

    public function dirsep()
    {
        return DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    public function dirname($file)
    {
        return $this->getCleanPath(dirname($file));
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Did you choose the format: 1.9.0.0-1.9.0.1 when downloading the path here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Comment: Do you have all the previous patches installed - you should be able to see this from app/etc/applied.patches.list I also suggest posting whats in lib/Varien/Io/File.rej (if it exists)

Comment: Yes, that is the patch I downloaded. The file name is PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-45-14

Comment: Hi, I will check app/etc/applied.patches.list, the contents of lib/Varien/Io/File.rej has just been edited in.

Comment: I have checked the patch list and it would appear 7616, 6237, 5994 & 4291/4334 were missing, does the order in which they are installed matter? I have just noticed that 7616 was released the same time as 7405, does it need to be installed first?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After many attempts, i went and applied all patches that were newer from the magento version we are using one by one, i can say that the above error is caused by a not applied previous patch or some other code change to the core files.

1. Check your **magento version** in admin in the footer
2. Go to the **Magento downloads** page and check the release date of your version
3. Make sure that every patch that is released later then your version is applied to your magento install by checking the file under /app/etc/applied.patches.list

Make sure **all available patches are applied** otherwise you will not be able to apply the latest patches including the SUPEE-7405 patch.

Comment: I have checked and we are up to date on all our patches the file 
lib/Varien/Io/File.php was altered in the patch 5994 (which shows up in the applied.patches.list as 5998. But there does not appear to have been any errors when this patch was installed so I'm not sure why this patch is not workign with it

Comment: I believe that you initially applied SUPEE-6285 which had anotehr release a week after the initial: 

[quote]Note: if you have previously applied patch PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1, please revert it and apply PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2. More information on reverting and applying patches is available here.[quote] We ended up downloading the initial code that matched our version and then running the patches one by one up untill the last one.

Comment: I have checked we are up to date on patches and do have 6285 v.2

Comment: The last solution that should work 100% is to download the release that your magento has at moment(1.9.1.0 was the one we had), replace existing code with it and apply all patches after your magento version release in the proper order up until the last one as we did. This way you will be absolutely sure that the core code is 100% up to date and future patches and upgrades should run smoothly.

Comment: I have had a look and all our patches are in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

What can we see at the end of the log

```
checking file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 227.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
```

Let's look at the patch and at the method near 227 row:

```
public function streamWriteCsv(array $row, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"')
{
    if (!$this->_streamHandler) {
        return false;
    }
    return @fputcsv($this->_streamHandler, $row, $delimiter, $enclosure);
}
```

But in patch it refers to some un-existed code:

```
diff --git lib/Varien/Io/File.php lib/Varien/Io/File.php
index bdc9bd7..65a2412 100644
--- lib/Varien/Io/File.php
+++ lib/Varien/Io/File.php
@@ -227,16 +227,6 @@ class Varien_Io_File extends Varien_Io_Abstract
             return false;
         }

-        /**
-         * Security enchancement for CSV data processing by Excel-like applications.
-         * @see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1054702
-         */
-        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
-            if (substr($value, 0, 1) === '=') {
-                $row[$key] = ' ' . $value;
-            }
-        }
-
         return @fputcsv($this->_streamHandler, $row, $delimiter, $enclosure);
     }
```

As you can see there no such code in this method! No any foreach with some long comment.

## You may edit patch text on your own risk!

I don't know exactly where this code should present (maybe some patch adds it), but I don't know! As I understand the main idea to delete this code from Varien_Io_File. As there no such code, I edited patch and removed this part.

**p.s. If someone knows why it happen, please edit my post or add it as comment or separate answer.**

**I downloaded 1.9.0.1 magento from official site and saw that method also doesn't contain code for deletion**